# Where to upload files in Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, amazon-s3

I have a web application developed using Servlet and JSP, we will be hosting this in [Daily Razor Privat Tomcat Hosting](http://www.dailyrazor.com/java-jsp-hosting/private-tomcat-hosting/) soon.

But, now we have a problem. We have a form where the users can upload files to the server, files like images and PDF's. Now, we are not sure in which place we should save these files in server. I have seen lot of Stackoverflow answers telling the user to use the path like "C:/Upload/.." but this is a real product, so this is not gonna work.

I contacted the hosting company about this matter and all they said is they will give the FTP logging details once I purchased the system, no word about where to upload the files.

I also thought about uploading to Amazon S3, but we have to create folders "dynamically" for each user and subfolders for their uploaded content, therefor I am not so sure about S3. Apart from that, I believe S3 will drain my wallet.

Any advice about the upload location in tomcat or an alternate will be really appreciated.

Comment: S3 is quite inexpensive for something the size of PDFs and most images--it's something like 3¢/GB/month--and doesn't actually have "folders", just a convention of pretending that slashes in keys are folders.

Answer (score 0):

> But, now we have a problem. We have a form where the users can upload files to the server, files like images and PDF's. Now, we are not sure in which place we should save these files in server.

If you're talking about long-term storage then there's no correct answer here.  You'd just need to find a place on the server where your Tomcat user has permissions to write and configure the application to put them there.

> I contacted the hosting company about this matter and all they said is they will give the FTP logging details once I purchased the system, no word about where to upload the files.

Once you have FTP details, you should be able to connect to the server and look at the file system.  Presumably this would allow you to see the path where your application will be deployed.  From there, it's just a matter of picking a location where you'd want to save the files.

I'm not familiar with that hosting provider, so I can't really same more.

> I also thought about uploading to Amazon S3, but we have to create folders "dynamically" for each user and subfolders for their uploaded content, therefor I am not so sure about S3. Apart from that, I believe S3 will drain my wallet.

This can also be a good option, depending on your needs.  Price is definitely something to evaluate.  Demand and bandwidth on your hosting environment are others.  If you have high demand on these resources, putting them on AWS will take the load of your server and not eat up the bandwidth allocation from your hosting provider.

You could also store your uploads in a database.  I'm not personally a fan of this, but some people do it and I hear it works fine for them.